# NewRelic install on centos and cpanel

Tags: php, centos, cpanel

I'm trying to install NewRelic on my website, I use PHP, cPanel(VPS/dedicated) and Centos (64bit) for my server, I've installed the server monitoring part right on my server but when I try to install the 'app' part on my server I can't get that to install, I followed the instruction links http://newrelic.com/docs/php/new-relic-for-php

but to no success, has anyone got any ideas as to why this maybe? I have restared httpd and appache multiple times and given it some time to propogate etc..

Comment: *"I can't get that to install" ... "no success"* - Can you be more specific? Error message? How do you know it's not working? Don't be afraid to explain it like I'm 5 years old.

Comment: Sure thanks for the reply, ok the 'server' bit is working fine on new relic, but when you click on the tab 'applications' it just shows the page saying I need to install it for PHP, just as if you signed up for teh first time, thats what is shown, Thanks

Comment: Have you set the license key? http://newrelic.com/docs/php/proxy-daemon-newreliccfg-settings#cfgvar-license_key I setup New Relic the other day on a dev server for testing and had the same response until I realised I had forgotten the license key.

Comment: Yeah just doubled checked the licence key is there.. I don't know this is happening.. I've probably missed soemthing else.. anyone got any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem of this is having WHM installed and many PHP services installed, you should try this guide I found:

[New Relic for PHP w/cPanel](http://web.archive.org/web/20160416122206/http://www.networkredux.com:80/answers/hosting/control-panels/whm-cpanel/how-do-i-install-new-relic-php-cpanel)

Answer (score 1):

We have few dedicated servers on HostGator. Few months back we had installed "NewRelic" on our server for monitoring, later we started having issues and here is what HostGator Tech Team said

> "While it's possible to configure a cPanel server to use a non-cPanel
>   PHP version, it's complicated to configure and we will not support it
>   or set it up. PHP gets compiled from source by cPanel normally and it
>   should be left this way, as it interacts with a number of other
>   components on the server in complicated ways, as you found out today.
>   We recommend completely removing the custom "Newrelic" repository as
>   well as the packages it installed in order to avoid further
>   compatibility problems."

and here is what "NewRelic" team said

> "I wasn't trying to suggest that Hostgator's assertion was wrong. I
>   was just trying to figure out which instructions to go over with you."

Make sure to check compatibility before installing it. Installation instruction can be found at http://www.networkredux.com/answers/view/Hosting/Control_Panels/WHM/cPanel/162

Answer (score 0):

New Relic Needs to document this cpanel compatibility better, I know it's my fault for not researching but while using a hostgator dedicated server with cpanel/whm I got new relic up and running. . then my server became a huge mess if improperly configured files and a few days of reading and learning to get it straightened out - I understand my fault entirely but a big ass CPANEL/WHM <- CAREFULL sign might have helped :P